# session.invalidate() IllegalStateException

Tags: java, session, exception

I'm trying to invalidate a session. When I call:

```
session.invalidate()
```

it throws

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: getLastAccessedTime: Session already invalidated

Any idea why? I can see the session and it's values just before the invalidate line.

Comment: Err, because you've already invalidated the session?

Comment: It happens on that line, not after that :)

Comment: So? obviously the exception message means something. Possibly you have executed that line of code twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an HttpSessionListener to understand where and when the Session is timing-out or getting invalidated before you call the invalidate yourself.