# Redirect user to specific page when user is inactive for a specified time

Tags: session, redirect, servlets, servlet-filters

I want to program my servlet to block the session without closing if the user is inactive for 10 minutes and redirect the user to the page `sessionlocked.jsp`.

I tested this code, but it does not work.

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(10*60);
if (request.getSession(false) == null) {
    response.sendRedirect(url);
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html);

> setMaxInactiveInterval(int interval)
>
> Specifies the time, in seconds, between client requests before the servlet container will **invalidate this session.**

So `setMaxInactiveInterval` method does not meet your needs, it invalidates the session.

To show a locked page to the users, you have two options;

First;

> Use filters to check session time and if time is over redirect to
>   lockedpage otherwise reset time.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession(false);
    if (session == null) {
        // ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession(true);
        // redirect to logout or anywhere you want, to create a session
        return;
    }
    // Check if filter also work for sessionlocked.jsp
    if (((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURL().toString().contains("sessionlocked")) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response); // no need to check sessionlocked
        return;
    }
    long lastAccessTime = session.getLastAccessedTime();
    long tenMinuteAsMilisecond = 10 * 60 * 1000;
    if (lastAccessTime + tenMinuteAsMilisecond > (new Date()).getTime()) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response); // session still not locked
    } else {
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("sessionlocked.jsp");
    }
}
```

Second(In addition to First because First attempt is controlled on server side);

> Use javascript to count down and when time is over, redirect user to
>   the locked page.

```
 window.onload = function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            window.location.replace("/sessionlocked.jsp");
              }, 600000);
    }
```

if only need servlet; (when user interaction with servlet)

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session == null) {
        request.getSession(true);
        // redirect to logout or anywhere you want, to create a session
        return;
    }
    long lastAccessTime = session.getLastAccessedTime();
    long tenMinuteAsMilisecond = 10 * 1000;// to test lock time set to 10 seconds
    if (lastAccessTime + tenMinuteAsMilisecond > (new Date()).getTime()) {
        response.getOutputStream().print("Session not locked" + i++);
        // TODO for not locked code
    } else {
        response.getOutputStream().print("Session locked");
         //redirect to sessionlocked.jsp
    }
}
```

Servlet Output (lock time set to 10 seconds);
[image: Servlet output]

Comment: Filter attempt won't work if session is expired (getSession() will give you a new one). JS attempt gives strange results when client has multiple pages (tabs/windows) open on same session. None of both is the correct approach to the requirement of immediately redirecting an user when the session is expired on server side.

Comment: @BalusC I'm still editing the answer, guessed that and add a comment above of the code, I think answer is not deserved -1 point, it is an impatient action :)

Comment: The answer is in its current form just wrong. Of course the downvote will be removed if the post is corrected in such way that it actually answers and solves the concrete requirement and describes all possible caveats when a workaround is proposed instead of a solution.

Comment: I tested it on several scenarios, I hope it helps to Ghanesoft as expected.

Comment: I want configure it  using servlet (server)  not using javascript (client)

Comment: @Ghanesoft You can't forward page on servlet without any request. So if you want to redirect on servlet check the updated answer

Comment: i tested last code but i have this error :

Etat HTTP 500 - "getLastAccessedTime" already invalidate

Comment: @Ghanesoft Servlet code works as seen on gif, try it in an empty project and then integrate it to your project. The 'already invalidate' exception is not about that example. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/6055187/517134

Comment: Thank you my Friend,
I use only service method on my servlet:  i have this error : Etat HTTP 500 - "getLastAccessedTime" already invalidate :( 
its work in service method ?